# Why can we do a flux integral over a surface but not a flow integral

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, vector-analysis, line-integrals

In 2d vector fields, we learn how to do two types of integrals: flow integrals and flux integral over a curve. My question is, why can we do flux integrals in 3D over a surface, but not flow integrals ? We can do a flow integral over a line in 3D, but why not over a surface ?

Comment: I guess by a "flow integral," you mean integrating the component of a vector field tangent to the surface. There's no reason you *can't* do this, it just not really useful to do so (that I know of — maybe someone has a use for it).

Comment: Isn’t curl a ‘flow integral’? @user37496